# How can I draw filled points in my line chart using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I'm trying to draw a DISC Personality Test chart. So far, by looking up some tutorials, I maneged to draw a basic line chart with empty points like this:
[image: Disc Chart Before]

But I wanted to draw a line chart with filled data points. How can I do this?

Comment: Is not clear what exactly you are trying to fix, you applied fillStyle and the lines space between the lines gets filled, is that not what you intended?

Comment: I'm still learning this so no, it's not what I wanted. I want the first graph like that but with black points, not white...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Chart.js v3.9:

It can be done with `pointBackgroundColor` propety:

```
type: "line",
data: {
    labels: ['', 'D', 'I', 'S', 'C', ''],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'myLabel',
        data: myData,
        borderColor:'#FF82E2',            
        pointBorderWidth: 2,              
        pointRadius: 6.25,                
        pointBackgroundColor: "#FF82E2", //
        pointBorderColor: "#FF82E2"
    }]
}
```

ref: [Chartjs/Point-styling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point-styling)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of examples of using fill and stroke

This is just same as your code where everything is just inside one big beginPath and closePath.

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx3 = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx3.beginPath();
ctx3.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx3.arc(10, 10, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx3.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx3.arc(50, 50, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx3.lineTo(100, 50);
ctx3.arc(100, 50, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx3.closePath();

ctx3.fillStyle = "black";
ctx3.fill();
ctx3.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx3.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="120"></canvas>
```

---

Here we break down the drawing of the lines and the drawing of the circles

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx3 = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx3.strokeStyle = "black";

array = [{x:10,y:10,c:"gray"}, {x:50,y:50,c:"red"}, {x:100, y:50,c:"cyan"}]

ctx3.beginPath();
ctx3.moveTo(10, 10);
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){  
  ctx3.lineTo(array[i].x, array[i].y);
}
ctx3.stroke();
ctx3.closePath();

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  ctx3.beginPath();
  ctx3.fillStyle = array[i].c;
  ctx3.arc(array[i].x, array[i].y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx3.fill();
  ctx3.stroke();
  ctx3.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="120"></canvas>
```

You can see that with individual beginPath and closePath per arc we can even pick different fill color, that is just one sugestion you can try